# How can I add to a 3d arrayList without just overwriting previous entries?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, arraylist

**I'm trying to add to a 3d array as below:**

`ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> bigList = new ArrayList<>();`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> smallList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**But when I add like below:**

```
bigList.add(smallList);
```

**It just overwrites previous entries**

How can I fix?

Comment: From the code you posted, it's unclear what you mean by "it just overwrites previous entries". Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: Is my method of adding to a 3d ArrayList correct?

Comment: @FilmVersion no. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit confused in your approach.  Here is a working example of how to add ArrayLists to a 3d ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> masterList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> middleList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> middleList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> innerList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> innerList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> innerList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> innerList4 = new ArrayList<>();

    innerList1.add("String 1");
    innerList1.add("String 2");
    innerList2.add("String 3");
    innerList2.add("String 4");
    innerList3.add("String 5");
    innerList3.add("String 6");
    innerList4.add("String 7");
    innerList4.add("String 8");

    middleList1.add(innerList1);
    middleList1.add(innerList2);
    middleList2.add(innerList3);
    middleList2.add(innerList4);

    System.out.println(masterList.size()); //output:  0
    masterList.add(middleList1);
    System.out.println(masterList.size()); //output:  1
    masterList.add(middleList2);
    System.out.println(masterList.size()); //output:  2
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not 100% sure, but see if this helps:

```
    String[][][] bigList=new String[how"wide"][how"tall"][how"fat"]
```

Comment: That's not an arrayList. And it doesn't tell me how to add to a 3d array correctly?